# Problem using variable name in R function when reading in a .yaml file

Tags: r, yaml

I am having problems with using a function variable when loading a .yaml file in R.

My .yaml file looks like this:

```
dataset_1: |

  This is dataset 1.

dataset_2: |

  This is dataset 2
```

If I do:

```
yaml.load_file("report/myfile.yaml")$dataset_1
```

or

```
yaml.load_file("report/myfile.yaml")$dataset_2
```

It works correctly.  However, this function doesn't work:

```
mypage <- function(name){
    yaml.load_file("report/myfile.yaml")$name
}
```

Where `name` would be `dataset_1` or `dataset_2`.

Why is it not taking the variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `$` with names stored in variables. Use `[[` instead:

```
yaml.load_file("report/myfile.yaml")[[name]]
```

And you'll call your function with a string input in quotes, `mypage("dataset_2")`.

(This is the same with data frames, e.g., `mtcars$mpg` is the `mpg` column of `mtcars`. But if you have `var = "mpg"`, then `mtcars$var` doesn't work, you need to use `mtcars[[var]]`.)